# On use ko.bindingHandlers memory is not releasing in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having knockout binding :
https://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/no01hnv1/3/

HTML

```
<div id="main" data-bind='dispose: $data'>
</div>
<button type="button" id="remove" value="Press">Press</button>
```

JS:

```
function getArray()
{
    var myArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        myArray.push('hello');
    }
    return myArray;
}

function Model() {
    console.log('model created');
    this.name = [];
}

Model.prototype.dispose = function () {
    console.log('model disposed');
}

var model = new Model();
model.name = getArray();
var container = document.getElementById('main');

ko.bindingHandlers.dispose = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            model.dispose()
        })
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model, container);

$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    ko.removeNode(container);
});
```

I am simply creating a model and `dispose` bindingHandlers which i am binding to div.

Then there is `Press` button, on click of which i am removing the node.

When i check memory in task manger, the memory is not releasing on removal of node.

I use `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback`. The execution comes into this method, but still memory is not released.

Comment: Which memory are you expecting to get released?

Comment: browser memory should get released

Comment: Yes, but for what object?  If `model`, you still have a reference to it within your `addDisposeCallback` callback.  JavaScript can't tell that logically it's not needed anymore.  One wonders if this might be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - do you have an underlying problem that's driven you to this point?

Comment: even i remove model.dispose() in addDisposeCallback, memory didn't released

Comment: well `var model` also exists in the global scope too.

Comment: Yes but, for normal javascript, if you have any variable in global scope and its not in use, GC remove its memory.

Comment: Not without first doing, eg `model = null`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe i tried with null it didn't work for me.

Comment: @JamesThorpe  Please check https://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/no01hnv1/3